# I have webpack.getAppPath error on old nativescript project

Tags: android, webpack, nativescript

I am new to Nativescript and I get this error. what can I use instead of webpack.getapppath.

```
TypeError: nsWebpack.getAppPath is not a function
    at module.exports (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/webpack.config.js:39:49)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/dist/bin/index.js:67:44)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:488:17)
    at /Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1227:65
    at Command._chainOrCall (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1144:12)
    at Command._parseCommand (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1227:27)
    at Command._dispatchSubcommand (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1050:25)
    at Command._parseCommand (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:1193:19)
    at Command.parse (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/commander/lib/command.js:897:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/murataktay/Downloads/terapist_api_ve_mobile/terapistmobile-master/node_modules/@nativescript/webpack/dist/bin/index.js:123:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
No configuration!
Executing webpack failed with exit code 0.
```